# How to push all object into one object array based on some conditions

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, arraylist

I have an array of objects, I want to push it to one object if certain condition meet.
I want to group data based on some conditions. but I want to push it to one array instead of making it parent and child.

Here is my object array

```js
var myData = [{
"portfolio": "Consumer",
"regiserDate": "2021-01-27",
"sendType": "Capitalization",
"amount": 1000,
"__typename": "taxCalculation"
}, 
{
"portfolio": "Consumer",
"regiserDate": "2021-01-27",
"sendType": "Capitalization",
"amount": 3000,
"__typename": "taxCalculation"
},
{
"portfolio": "Consumer",
"regiserDate": "2021-01-27",
"sendType": "Capitalization",
"amount": 6000,
"__typename": "taxCalculation"
},
{
"portfolio": "Consumer",
"regiserDate": "2021-01-27",
"sendType": "Capitalization",
"amount": 7000,
"__typename": "taxCalculation"
},
 {
"portfolio": "Commercial",
"regiserDate": "2021-02-27",
"sendType": "Accure",
"amount": 999,
"__typename": "taxCalculation"
}, 
{
"portfolio": "Commercial",
"regiserDate": "2021-02-27",
"sendType": "Accure",
"amount": 9999,
"__typename": "taxCalculation"
},
 {
"portfolio": "Commercial",
"regiserDate": "2021-02-27",
"sendType": "Capitalization",
"amount": 3,
"__typename": "taxCalculation"
}, 
 {
"portfolio": "Commercial",
"regiserDate": "2021-01-27",
"sendType": "Accure",
"amount": 4,
"__typename": "taxCalculation"
}, 
 {
"portfolio": "Commercial",
"regiserDate": "2021-04-27",
"sendType": "Capitalization",
"amount": 6,
"__typename": "taxCalculation"
}, 
 {
"portfolio": "Retail",
"regiserDate": "2021-05-27",
"sendType": "Capitalization",
"amount": 7,
"__typename": "taxCalculation"
}, 
 {
"portfolio": "Retail",
"regiserDate": "2021-06-27",
"sendType": "Capitalization",
"amount": 8,
"__typename": "taxCalculation"
}, 
 {
"portfolio": "Retail",
"regiserDate": "2021-02-27",
"sendType": "Capitalization",
"amount": 10,
"__typename": "taxCalculation"
}, 
 {
"portfolio": "Retail",
"regiserDate": "2021-07-27",
"sendType": "payable",
"amount": 12,
"__typename": "taxCalculation"
}, 
 {
"portfolio": "Retail",
"regiserDate": "2021-01-27",
"sendType": "Accure",
"amount": 13,
"__typename": "taxCalculation"
}, 
 {
"portfolio": "Retail",
"regiserDate": "2021-09-27",
"sendType": "Accure",
"amount": 14,
"__typename": "taxCalculation"
}, 
 {
"portfolio": "Consumer",
"regiserDate": "2021-08-27",
"sendType": "Accure",
"amount": 16,
"__typename": "taxCalculation"
}, 
 {
"portfolio": "Consumer",
"regiserDate": "2021-09-27",
"sendType": "Accure",
"amount": 17,
"__typename": "taxCalculation"
}, 
 {
"portfolio": "Consumer",
"regiserDate": "2021-11-27",
"sendType": "Accure",
"amount": 18,
"__typename": "taxCalculation"
}, 
 {
"portfolio": "Retail",
"regiserDate": "2021-11-27",
"sendType": "Accure",
"amount": 19,
"__typename": "taxCalculation"
}, 
 {
"portfolio": "Retail",
"regiserDate": "2021-01-27",
"sendType": "payable",
"amount": 20,
"__typename": "taxCalculation"
}, 
 {
"portfolio": "Retail",
"regiserDate": "2021-01-27",
"sendType": "Accure",
"amount": 21,
"__typename": "taxCalculation"
}, 
 {
"portfolio": "Consumer",
"regiserDate": "2021-01-27",
"sendType": "Accure",
"amount": 22,
"__typename": "taxCalculation"
}, {
"portfolio": "Consumer",
"regiserDate": "2021-12-27",
"sendType": "Accure",
"amount": 28,
"__typename": "taxCalculation"
}, 
 {
"portfolio": "Consumer",
"regiserDate": "2021-11-27",
"sendType": "payable",
"amount": 30,
"__typename": "taxCalculation"
}, 
 {
"portfolio": "Consumer",
"regiserDate": "2021-01-27",
"sendType": "AccureAccureAccure",
"amount": 33,
"__typename": "taxCalculation"
}, 
 {
"portfolio": "Consumer",
"regiserDate": "2021-01-27",
"sendType": "AccureAccure",
"amount": 35,
"__typename": "taxCalculation"
}, 
 {
"portfolio": "Consumer",
"regiserDate": "2021-01-27",
"sendType": "Accure",
"amount": 45,
"__typename": "taxCalculation"
}, 
 {
"portfolio": "Consumer",
"regiserDate": "2021-04-27",
"sendType": "Capitalization",
"amount": 49,
"__typename": "taxCalculation"
}, 
 {
"portfolio": "Commercial",
"regiserDate": "2021-07-27",
"sendType": "payable",
"amount": 87,
"__typename": "taxCalculation"
}, 
 {
"portfolio": "Commercial",
"regiserDate": "2021-07-27",
"sendType": "Capitalization",
"amount": 81,
"__typename": "taxCalculation"
}, 
 {
"portfolio": "Commercial",
"regiserDate": "2021-08-27",
"sendType": "Accure",
"amount": 65,
"__typename": "taxCalculation"
}, 
 {
"portfolio": "Commercial",
"regiserDate": "2021-01-27",
"sendType": "payable",
"amount": 470,
"__typename": "taxCalculation"
}, 
 {
"portfolio": "Commercial",
"regiserDate": "2021-05-27",
"sendType": "payable",
"amount": 540,
"__typename": "taxCalculation"
}
];
```

I want to combine into one array object if "portfolio" and "sendType" are same.
my expected result should be like

```js
var result = [{
"portfolio": "Consumer",
"sendType": "Capitalization",
"2021-01-27": "23",
"2021-04-27": "45",
"2021-06-27": "79",
"2021-07-27": "19",
"2021-11-27": "45",
"2021-08-27": "90",
"__typename": "taxCalculation"
}, 
{
"portfolio": "Consumer",
"sendType": "Accure",
"2022-01-27": "34",
"2022-04-27": "786",
"2022-06-27": "20",
"2022-07-27": "78",
"2022-11-27": "20",
"2022-08-27": "45",
},
{
"portfolio": "Commercial",
"sendType": "Accure",
"2021-01-27": "26",
"2021-12-27": "23",
"2021-06-27": "28",
"2021-07-27": "29",
"2021-11-27": "21",
"2021-08-27": "23",
"__typename": "taxCalculation"
},
{
"portfolio": "Retail",
"sendType": "payable",
"2022-01-27": "25",
"2023-12-27": "27",
"2023-06-27": "29",
"2022-07-27": "22",
"2022-11-27": "24",
"2021-08-27": "27",
"__typename": "taxCalculation"
}
]
```

Comment: Are you sure that what you posted for the final result is actually the right structure? You plan to have the same key repeated in the object? Must be a mistake. Maybe you meant one key (regiserDate) with array of date-strings as value, for example?

Comment: yes I am sure, I need the same portfolio and sendType, and the date and amount should be appended.

Comment: You can't have multiple properties with the same key in the same object.  Just paste your "expected" result into an IDE and see all the errors.  So what you're asking for is impossible, which makes it hard for others to help you .  Please [edit] that code to be an actual [mre], or this question will probably be closed as needing clarity.  Good luck!

Comment: hi @jcalz thanks for your suggestion, you are right. 
I update the expected result. thanks,
Please can you help me to solve it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the algorithm to do all of that would be:

```js
var myData = [{
    "portfolio": "Consumer",
    "regiserDate": "2021-01-27",
    "sendType": "Capitalization",
    "amount": 1,
    "__typename": "taxCalculation"
}, 
 {
    "portfolio": "Commercial",
    "regiserDate": "2021-02-27",
    "sendType": "Accure",
    "amount": 2,
    "__typename": "taxCalculation"
}, 
 {
    "portfolio": "Commercial",
    "regiserDate": "2021-02-27",
    "sendType": "Capitalization",
    "amount": 3,
    "__typename": "taxCalculation"
}, 
 {
    "portfolio": "Commercial",
    "regiserDate": "2021-01-27",
    "sendType": "Accure",
    "amount": 4,
    "__typename": "taxCalculation"
}, 
 {
    "portfolio": "Commercial",
    "regiserDate": "2021-04-27",
    "sendType": "Capitalization",
    "amount": 6,
    "__typename": "taxCalculation"
}, 
 {
    "portfolio": "Retail",
    "regiserDate": "2021-05-27",
    "sendType": "Capitalization",
    "amount": 7,
    "__typename": "taxCalculation"
}, 
 {
    "portfolio": "Retail",
    "regiserDate": "2021-06-27",
    "sendType": "Capitalization",
    "amount": 8,
    "__typename": "taxCalculation"
}, 
 {
    "portfolio": "Retail",
    "regiserDate": "2021-02-27",
    "sendType": "Capitalization",
    "amount": 10,
    "__typename": "taxCalculation"
}, 
 {
    "portfolio": "Retail",
    "regiserDate": "2021-07-27",
    "sendType": "payable",
    "amount": 12,
    "__typename": "taxCalculation"
}, 
 {
    "portfolio": "Retail",
    "regiserDate": "2021-01-27",
    "sendType": "Accure",
    "amount": 13,
    "__typename": "taxCalculation"
}, 
 {
    "portfolio": "Retail",
    "regiserDate": "2021-09-27",
    "sendType": "Accure",
    "amount": 14,
    "__typename": "taxCalculation"
}, 
 {
    "portfolio": "Consumer",
    "regiserDate": "2021-08-27",
    "sendType": "Accure",
    "amount": 16,
    "__typename": "taxCalculation"
}, 
 {
    "portfolio": "Consumer",
    "regiserDate": "2021-09-27",
    "sendType": "Accure",
    "amount": 223,
    "__typename": "taxCalculation"
}, 
 {
    "portfolio": "Consumer",
    "regiserDate": "2021-11-27",
    "sendType": "Accure",
    "amount": 24,
    "__typename": "taxCalculation"
}, 
 {
    "portfolio": "Retail",
    "regiserDate": "2021-11-27",
    "sendType": "Accure",
    "amount": 256,
    "__typename": "taxCalculation"
}, 
 {
    "portfolio": "Retail",
    "regiserDate": "2021-01-27",
    "sendType": "payable",
    "amount": 45,
    "__typename": "taxCalculation"
}, 
 {
    "portfolio": "Retail",
    "regiserDate": "2021-01-27",
    "sendType": "Accure",
    "amount": 435,
    "__typename": "taxCalculation"
}, 
 {
    "portfolio": "Consumer",
    "regiserDate": "2021-01-27",
    "sendType": "Accure",
    "amount": 4543,
    "__typename": "taxCalculation"
}, {
    "portfolio": "Consumer",
    "regiserDate": "2021-12-27",
    "sendType": "Accure",
    "amount": 4534,
    "__typename": "taxCalculation"
}, 
 {
    "portfolio": "Consumer",
    "regiserDate": "2021-11-27",
    "sendType": "payable",
    "amount": 8,
    "__typename": "taxCalculation"
}, 
 {
    "portfolio": "Consumer",
    "regiserDate": "2021-01-27",
    "sendType": "AccureAccureAccure",
    "amount": 90,
    "__typename": "taxCalculation"
}, 
 {
    "portfolio": "Consumer",
    "regiserDate": "2021-01-27",
    "sendType": "AccureAccure",
    "amount": 88,
    "__typename": "taxCalculation"
}, 
 {
    "portfolio": "Consumer",
    "regiserDate": "2021-01-27",
    "sendType": "Accure",
    "amount": 45,
    "__typename": "taxCalculation"
}, 
 {
    "portfolio": "Consumer",
    "regiserDate": "2021-04-27",
    "sendType": "Capitalization",
    "amount": 49,
    "__typename": "taxCalculation"
}, 
 {
    "portfolio": "Commercial",
    "regiserDate": "2021-07-27",
    "sendType": "payable",
    "amount": 29,
    "__typename": "taxCalculation"
}, 
 {
    "portfolio": "Commercial",
    "regiserDate": "2021-07-27",
    "sendType": "Capitalization",
    "amount": 81,
    "__typename": "taxCalculation"
}, 
 {
    "portfolio": "Commercial",
    "regiserDate": "2021-08-27",
    "sendType": "Accure",
    "amount": 90,
    "__typename": "taxCalculation"
}, 
 {
    "portfolio": "Commercial",
    "regiserDate": "2021-01-27",
    "sendType": "payable",
    "amount": 47,
    "__typename": "taxCalculation"
}, 
 {
    "portfolio": "Commercial",
    "regiserDate": "2021-05-27",
    "sendType": "payable",
    "amount": 54,
    "__typename": "taxCalculation"
}
];

const indicesMap = new Map();

const results = [];

for ( let i = 0; i < myData.length; i++ ) {

  let key = `${ myData[i].portfolio }${ myData[i].sendType }`;

  if ( indicesMap.has( key ) ) {

    const index = indicesMap.get( key );

    const obj = results[ index ];

    obj[ myData[ i ].regiserDate ] = myData[ i ].amount;

  } else {

    const obj = {

      sendType:myData[ i ].sendType,
      portfolio:myData[ i ].portfolio,
      __typename:myData[ i ].__typename,
      [ myData[ i ].regiserDate ]: myData[ i ].amount

    }

    results.push( obj )

    indicesMap.set( key, results.length - 1 );

  }

}
  
indicesMap.clear()

console.log( results );
```

Comment: hi @jSmith, the solution need a little modification, I update the expected result. Please if you can help me in that again too.

Comment: @JolenQadar what di you changed? I saw you changed the values, well it is the exact same alogrithm for different values.So execpt if I misunderstood something, the solution I've provided you still works.

Comment: I changed the expected result, please can you check the question again. now I want like{
"portfolio": "Commercial",
"sendType": "Accure",
"2021-01-27": "20",
"2021-12-27": "20",
"2021-06-27": "20",
"2021-07-27": "20",
"2021-11-27": "20",
"2021-08-27": "20",
"__typename": "taxCalculation"
}

Comment: I want the registereDate value as a key and the amount value is the value for those keys

Comment: @JolenQadar I can't help you with that sorry I don't understand

Comment: @JolenQadar please make another question on stackoverflow

Comment: I update the question and expected result. but still thanks for your kind answer

Comment: sorry stack overflow is not allowing for a new post. I update the question and expected result again, hope it will clear to you. thanks

Comment: @JolenQadar I've changed my answer

Comment: @JolenQadar I've changed my answer again this should work now.Best

Comment: Thanks man, you are the real champ.it works.

Comment: I have some requirement changed, under the same keys (portfolio and type) for multiple dates, the amount need to aggregate, like first 4 objects amount should be like 1000+3000+6000+7000 = 16000

2021-01-27:16000
2021-04-27:49
portfolio:"Consumer"
sendType:"Capitalization"
__typename:"taxCalculation"

2021-01-27:4
2021-02-27:10987
2021-08-27:65
portfolio:"Commercial"
sendType:"Accure"
__typename:"taxCalculation"

Comment: please can you check it please.

Comment: my requirements are further modefied and I want to translate my object to anothe forum, please check this question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76338844/how-to-restructure-json-object-to-convert-from-one-form-to-another-form