# how to restructure json object to convert from one form to another form

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, javascript-objects

I have a scenario where my object has a date value as a key. I want to restructure the JSON so that every object has only one date.

I want the date value should assign to "education" and every object has only one date value.

The problem here is that my date is dynamic so I cant keep it as a key. The date can be variable. Each object should have one date and the value of the date should be assigned to education. For all the same date values then they should be in one object and the value of that date will be the value of the education.

This is the current data format and code:

```js
var arr = [{
  "education": "school",
  "2021-12": 65.45,
  "2022-01": 172762.27,
  "2022-02": "959.5"
}, {
  "education": "colleg",
  "2021-12": 270.13,
  "2022-01": 105429534.09,
  "2022-02": 53543770.9,
  "2022-03": 100004545
}, {
  "education": "university",
  "2021-12": 168396.95,
  "2022-01": 170417648.96999997,
  "2022-02": 1202822.9
}];

let result = [];
arr.forEach((element, index) => {
  let subObj = {}
  let keys = Object.keys(element);
  for (var propt in element) {
    if (keys.indexOf(propt) > -1) {
      if (element.hasOwnProperty('2021-12')) {
        subObj['education'] = element[propt]
      }
    }
  }
  result.push(subObj)
});

console.log(result);
```

This is the output I want:

```js
[{
  "school": "65.45",
  "colleg": "270.13",
  "university": "168396.95",
  "date": "2021-12"
}, {
  "school": "172762.",
  "colleg": "105429534.09",
  "university": "170417648.96999997",
  "date": "2022-01"
}, {
  "school": "959.5",
  "colleg": "53543770.9",
  "university": "1202822.9",
  "date": "2022-02"
}, {
  "colleg": "959.5",
  "date": "2022-03",
}]
```

Comment: Please take the [tour]  (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO and elsewhere, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mre] showing your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Note: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON. Your `arr` array just contains objects, not "JSON objects."

Comment: thanks TJ. is it possible what I mentioned in expected result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that "education" key is present in your array all the time, you can get your desired array like this:

```js
var arr = [{
  "education": "school",
  "2021-12": 65.45,
  "2022-01": 172762.27,
  "2022-02": "959.5"
}, {
  "education": "colleg",
  "2021-12": 270.13,
  "2022-01": 105429534.09,
  "2022-02": 53543770.9,
  "2022-03": 100004545
}, {
  "education": "university",
  "2021-12": 168396.95,
  "2022-01": 170417648.96999997,
  "2022-02": 1202822.9
}];

// Array for getting unique dates
let datesArray = [];
// Array for getting unique educations
let educationArray = [];

arr.forEach(item => {
  for (key in item) {
    if (key === "education") {
      // Check if this education already exists in array
      if (!educationArray.includes(item[key])) {
        educationArray.push(item[key]);
      }
      // Check if this date already exists in array
    } else if (!datesArray.includes(key)) {
      datesArray.push(key);
    }
  }
});

// Array for desired result
let finalResult = [];

datesArray.forEach(date => {
  let educationForThisDate = {};
  // Get educations for this date
  educationArray.forEach(education => {
    let educationValue = arr.filter(x => x['education'] === education)[0][date];
    // Check if education value exists for this date (we don't want to append education with value undefined)
    // Can also remove this if check if you want all educations regardless if they are undefined or null
    if (educationValue) {
      educationForThisDate[education] = educationValue.toString();
    }
  });
  educationForThisDate['date'] = date;

  finalResult.push(educationForThisDate);
});

console.log(finalResult);
```

This can also be optimized a little bit, but for now it does the job.